# Vertical expanding table

Tags: html, css

i'm new at HTML and CSS and I've got an issue with my th expanding horizontally while I want it to expand vertically. I've fixed the width of the Th but it isn't solving anything. This is my code.

```
<div id="resBox">
    <table id="resTable">
            <tr>
                <th class="frame">a</th>
                <th class="frame">b</th>
                <th class="frame">c</th>
                <th class="frame">d</th>
                <th class="frame">e</th>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Whenever a th contains a long string , it expends making the other frames smaller.

This is the css code :

```
#resTable{
width:100%;
margin:auto;}

.frame{
width:19%;
border: 1px solid black;}
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3M7px/ Take a look, because I suppose a code you gave us works. Or maybe it shouldn't look like this?

Comment: You're welcome ;D You propably have some other styles which overwrites those which you showed us :)

Comment: Actually , found out what went wrong. When testing the scale , I just composed a very long word. you need spaces so it comes back to lane. I will make it justified.

Comment: I apologize for the slightly vague comment but, you should check for an attribute that can wrap the text. :)
And add your answer and accept it so that others can refer to it

Answer (score 0):

Write this CSS -

```
table th{
    width: 100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Scec9/3/

Comment: Keep in mind that changing a `th` or `td` to `inline-block` breaks the normal table functionality (so you can wind up with some really funky results).

Answer (score 0):

there are no clear cut ways of doing this without involving some form of code behind or similar that can make sub strings, this is for long continous strings that is.

The closest you get is something like the things explained in this article:

http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html

However those methods will probably be excessively buggy.

Comment: To clarify, this is for CONTINOUS long strings without white spaces. As soon as you implement a white space it will break just fine with the markup you already have. :)